# Micrometer @Timed annotation

Tags: java, spring-boot, prometheus, micrometer

Can anyone explain me what are the differences between `_count` and `_sum` metrics exposed by micrometer `@Timed` annotation.

Here you have two examples of metrics values as results of a `@Timed` annotation post upon a method.

```
GET_CARD_LIMITS_BY_LIMIT_TYPE_seconds_count{class="ro.orange.productsbff.infrastructure.adapter.cms.integration.CmsClient",method="getCardLimitsByType",} 9.0

GET_CARD_LIMITS_BY_LIMIT_TYPE_seconds_sum{class="ro.orange.productsbff.infrastructure.adapter.cms.integration.CmsClient",method="getCardLimitsByType",} 1.838999262
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `count` is the total measurements that the timer has taken. The `sum` is the cumulative *duration* of all the measurements that the time has taken. So by dividing the sum by the count you can see that average timing:

```
GET_CARD_LIMITS_BY_LIMIT_TYPE_seconds_sum / 
GET_CARD_LIMITS_BY_LIMIT_TYPE_seconds_count
```

However that can become less useful over time since that average could hide spikes as the values grow.

Since both those numbers will only go up (accounting for restarts), Prometheus can leverage that knowledge and you can see the 1 minute average latency for that timer like so:

```
increase(GET_CARD_LIMITS_BY_LIMIT_TYPE_seconds_sum[1m]) /   
increase(GET_CARD_LIMITS_BY_LIMIT_TYPE_seconds_count[1m])
```